# Not null check with phonegap and jquery mobile

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm using phonegap 1.1.0 and jquery mobile rc1.

The following code works as expected in firefox 7.0.1 (it does not enter in the body of if statement if id_element_to_modify is not null). 
When running on android emulator i got the two alert displayed with
"id_element_to_modify1:null" and
"id_element_to_modify2:null"

Is it a bug ?

```
    var id_element_to_modify = window.localStorage.getItem("id_hour_to_modify_or_delete");
    alert("id_element_to_modify1:" + id_element_to_modify);
    if (null != id_element_to_modify){              
        alert("id_element_to_modify2:" + id_element_to_modify);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With phonegap-1.1.0, jquery-1.6.4, and jquery.mobile-1.0rc1, on android emulator, the following solution works for me.

```
var myVar = window.localStorage.getItem("myVar");

if (myVar == null) {

alert(myVar);

} else if (myVar != null) {

alert(myVar);

} else {

}
```

Comment: Thanks, it was a my error: id_element_to_modify was a string with "null" value. Putting window.localStorage.setItem(key, null) transforms the value into the string with value "null".